# Psycopg2 - Inserting complex query with strings + numbers?

Tags: python, database, postgresql, insert, psycopg2

I am having trouble trying to insert new rows into a Postgres database via Python. Using Psycopg2 library, I found that the expected code is something like what's below.

I have tried ordering all elements into a tuple and formatting it all into a single string. but the formatting obviously didn't work. I also tried separating them as it is shown in the code, but the error I get is:

unsupported format character 'd' (0x64) at index 805

I have checked the database structure which I'm trying to insert, and the formats coincide, meaning that I'm not trying to insert a string into a number or vice versa.

```py
my_query = ('INSERT INTO public.ad_performance (account, adgroupid, adtype,'
                    'campaignid, adid, ad) VALUES'
                    '(%s, %d, %s, %d, %d, %r)')


cur.execute(my_query, (account[i], adgroupid[i], adtype[i], campaignid[i], adid[i], False))

conn.commit()
```

I expected the insertion to successfully insert my row, but to no avail.
This is an example of the output produced (printing what I'm trying to insert):

```py
('INVERSION', 3681.0, 'ad-3', 201513041, 28.0, False)
```

Comment: As per the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries): *The variables placeholder must always be a `%s`, even if a different placeholder (such as a `%d` for integers or `%f` for floats) may look more appropriate*

Comment: Thanks shmee. If you add the answer again without a reply, I will mark the question solved.

Comment: I found a suitable dupe target instead :)